# Is at least one of L and L complement Turing recognizable

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines

Let the alphabet be {0,1}. Is it true that for every language over this alphabet at least 
one of L and L_complement is Turing-recognizable

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: I am unable to find any examples of non recognizable languages. We have examples of undecidable languages like Halting problem.

Answer (score 1):

No, try to think of a counting argument (i.e, the size of each class) in the following way:

There are $2^{\aleph_0}$ possible words in the language, hence $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ total languages. However, the number of turing machines is bounded by the total possible number of words (since you can encode a TM as a string), hence there are at most $2^{\aleph_0}$ TMs, and thus we get that $|RE| \le 2^{\aleph_0}$. Follow the definition of $co-RE$, to see that the same argument gives $|co-RE| \le 2^{\aleph_0}$ as well. Thus, $|RE\cup co-RE| \le 2^{\aleph_0}$ as well.

Thus $|RE\cup co-RE|\le 2^{\aleph_0}<2^{2^{\aleph_0}}=|P(\{0,1\}^*)|$, and thus there must be some $L\in P(\{0,1\}^*)\setminus (RE\cup co-RE)$ as you asked.

In fact, this shows there are *waaaaay* more languages that aren't RE or co-RE than languages that are.

Answer (score 0):

For a practical example of such a language, take a look at the following language:

$L = \{<M_1, M_2, w> | M_1 \text{ halts on } w \land M_2 \text{ doesn't halt on } w\}$

It is not in $co-RE$ since the halting problem isn't (there is a reduction from the halting problem to this problem)

And for a similar reason it is not in $RE$ (the complement of the halting problem is not in $RE$, and there is a reduction from $L$ to it)